# Closed-form formula for $\tan x+\frac12\tan\frac x2+\frac1{2^2}\tan\frac x{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}\tan\frac x{2^n}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the closed formula for
>   $$S=\tan x+\frac12\tan\frac x2+\frac1{2^2}\tan\frac x{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{2^n}\tan\frac x{2^n}$$

I tried some trigonometric identities, but I did not have success!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\cot x -\tan x=2\cot2x$$

$$\text{Multiply the sum by -1 and add}\space \space \frac{1}{2^n}\cot\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)\space \space\text{on both side }$$